# How can I create a wrapper around a controller function on node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, controller

My project uses express. I want to reuse some code that is currently on the controller.

```
getCustomersByCompanyId = async (req, res) => {
   ... some logic ...
}
```

```
getCustomersByCompanyId = async (req, res) => {

   const companyId = getCompanyByName(req.params.name)._id;

   // Here I want to do some kind of a wrapper around getCustomersByCompanyId
   // I have the id. But it seems that I need to send req contains that contains the id and not just the id as an argument... what's the best practice?
   return getCustomersByCompanyId(companyId); // <---- In other syntaxes I would do something like...
   
}
```

Comment: Make the function take an ID, and make the controller function separate, letting it call the other function with the right ID based on the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a service containing all the different functions that can be used multiple times and call that service's function when and where necessary.
For example, you can create a service of company and create a function of getCustomersByCompanyId(customerId) to return your data and use that function to the :

```
export class companyService {
   const customersByCompanyId = companyId => {
      <----------- logic here -------------->
   }
}
```

then you can use here:

```
getCustomersByCompanyId = async (req, res) => {
    return companyService.customersByCompanyId(req.param.companyId);
}
```

and here too:

```
getCustomersByCompanyIdAsOtherController = async (req, res) => {

   const companyId = getCompanyByName(req.params.name)._id;
   return companyService.customersByCompanyId(companyId);   
}
```